# while appending text Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that I want to print.

```
list_to_arry = ["a","b","c"];

$(".tooltip").append(for(var i =0; i< list_count.length; i++){list_to_array[i]});
```

Then I got an err like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for`

I have also tried it in this way

```
for(var i =0; i< list_count.length -1; i++){
    $(".tooltip").append(list_to_array[i]+"<br>");
}
```

but it is not printing anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `append()` takes in a function or string. You cannot put a `for` loop there, instead change it to:

```
var list_to_array = ["a","b","c"];
var list_count = list_to_array.length;
$(".tooltip").append(function () {
  final = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < list_count; i++)
    final += list_to_array[i];
  return final;
});
```

Also check the spellings. All are wrong. You have started with `list_to_arry`, then made it to `list_to_array`.

**Final Working Code**

```js
var list_to_array = ["a","b","c"];
var list_count = list_to_array.length;
$(".tooltip").append(function () {
  final = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < list_count; i++)
    final += list_to_array[i];
  return final;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip"></div>
```

If this is something similar, you can also use `Array.prototype.join()`:

```
var list_to_array = ["a","b","c"];
$(".tooltip").append(list_to_array.join(""));
```

The above gives the same result too.

**Ultimate Solution by [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1414562/a-wolff)**

The `.append()` also takes in an array:

```
var list_to_array = ["a","b","c"];
$(".tooltip").append(list_to_array);
```

So this should work as well. `:)`

Comment: [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content) can takes an array `$(".tooltip").append(list_to_array);` :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Wow... Didn't know that! `:)`

Comment: Ya, that's the main thing here :)

Comment: Any reason to make `final` global ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Ah, I see. I left the `var` is it? Take it as my mistake. Sorry.

Comment: I know but OP is going to __ctrl+c__ and __ctrl+v__. It will mess up things if he is already using `final`, quiet common word isn't it ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Okay, will make sure to provide proper code hereafter. `:)` But there would be nothing wrong in a small project I assume. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my gosh!! That is a simple typo error.

But still the first one of your snippets is wrong syntactically because `append` takes a function as an argument, but you were supplying a `for` loop there. The correct one is the second one, and that is just a typo error, using `arry` instead of `array`. Check below:

```
for(var i =0; i < list_to_array.length; i++){
    $(".tooltip").append(list_to_arry[i]+"<br>");
}   // --------------------------^^^^---- Typo here. Use of "arry" instead of array.
```

And I doubt about `list_count`. Maybe you should replace it with `list_to_arry`.

---

Or without a loop, you can use `.join('<br>')`:

```js
var list_to_arry = ["a", "b", "c"];
$(".tooltip").append(list_to_arry.join("<br>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='tooltip'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace** `list_count` in the `for` loop with `list_to_arry`.

You have written the wrong array name:

```
for (var i =0; i< list_to_arry.length -1; i++) {
    $(".tooltip").append(list_to_array[i]+"<br>");
}
```

BTW, you can't put a `for` loop directly inside the `.append()` method.

Answer (score 0):

[.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

> content
>
> Type: htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery
>   DOM element, array of elements, HTML string, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

This should help you understand the reason for the error.

Also, it's a bad practice to manipulate the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) inside a loop. You should create an HTML string and perform a bulk operation.

#### Simple loop with bulk operation

```js
var list_to_arry = ["a", "b", "c"];
var html = "";

for (var i = 0; i < list_to_arry.length; i++) {
    html+= list_to_arry[i]
}

$(".tooltip").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tooltip"></div>
```

#### Array.join

If your data structure is this simple, you can even use `array.join()`:

```js
var list_to_arry = ["a", "b", "c"];

$(".tooltip").append(list_to_arry.join("<br/>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tooltip"></div>
```